# Как научить intellij idea понимать путь к ресурсам между папками static и templates от Spring Web?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-mvc

Я использую Spring Web и мое приложение имеет такой вид:

```
├───java
│   └───...
└───resources
    ├───static
    │   ├───css
    │   └───img
    └───templates
```

Есть папки `static` и `templates`.
И если я в `index.html` импортирую css файл `css/main.css`, тогда будет ошибка "Файл не найден".
И это логично, потому что фактический путь является `../static/css/main.css`.

Можно ли как-то научить IDEA понимать, что папки `static` и `templates` являются общем корнем сайта? Возможно есть какой-то плагин на IDEA, который я не включил?

Мои текущие включенные плагины в IDEA:

```
.ignore (3.0.0.182)
ASP (0.1)
AspectJ Support (1.2)
BashSupport (1.7.3)
Bytecode Viewer (0.1)
CFML Support (3.53)
Copyright (8.1)
CSS Support (182.4892.20)
Database Tools and SQL (182.4892.20)
DSM Analysis (1.0.0)
Eclipse Integration (3.0)
EditorConfig (182.4892.20)
Gherkin (999.999)
Git Integration (8.1)
GitHub (182.4892.20)
Gradle (182.4892.20)
Groovy (9.0)
Guice (8.0)
Hibernate Support (1.0)
I18n for Java (182.4892.20)
IDE Settings Sync (182.4892.20)
IntelliLang (8.0)
J2ME (1.0)
Java Bytecode Decompiler (182.4892.20)
Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets (1.0)
Java Server Pages (JSP) Integration (1.0)
Java Stream Debugger (182.4892.20)
JavaFX (1.0)
JavaScript Support (1.0)
JUnit (1.0)
Kotlin (1.2.51-release-IJ2018.2-1)
Lombok Plugin (0.19-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT)
Markdown support (182.4892.20)
Maven Integration (182.4892.20)
Maven Integration Extension (182.4892.20)
Persistence Frameworks Support (1.0)
Playframework Support (1.0)
Properties Support (182.4892.20)
Reactor framework support (1.0)
Refactor-X (2.01)
Remote Hosts Access (0.1)
Settings Repository (182.4892.20)
Smali Support (1.0)
Spring AOP/@AspectJ (1.0)
Spring Boot (1.0)
Spring MVC (1.0)
Spring Security (1.0)
Spring Support (1.0)
SSH Remote Run (0.1)
Task Management (1.0)
Terminal (0.1)
Thymeleaf (1.0)
Time Tracking (1.0)
UML Support (1.0)
Unit File Support (systemd) (0.1.0)
XPathView + XSLT Support (4)
XSLT-Debugger (1.4)
YAML (182.4892.20)
ZKM-Unscramble (1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело не в плагине. Это спринг))) Тут дело в коде. Как я вижу, ты используешь Thymeleaf -> вот пример импорта CSS:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Логин</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/login_css.css}">
</head>
<body>
// остальной код...
```

Comment: о спасибо!

а как в css прописывать? Я имею в виду, путь вида `background: url(/img/bg.jpg)`, чтобы оно понимало, что корень сайта это static папка

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук https://stackoverflow.com/a/10799957/8992586